# How can I retrieve the indices used to generate the max sum such that no adjacent elements are used?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, indexing

Below is my code, which produces the indices used, but in some cases, finds a value, and takes the first index containing that value, while I need the specific index from which that value came.

```
import random

numsLength = random.randint(1,100)
a = [random.randint(0, 400) for i in range(numsLength)]
DP = [[] for i in a]  # This will hold bestSeq from i, initially empty
seq = []
mineNum = []

def solveDP(i):
    global DP

    if i >= len(a):
        return []

    # If this value is already computed return that value
    if len(DP[i]) > 0:
        return DP[i]

    # Include the current element and go to i+2
    arr1 = [a[i]] + solveDP(i + 2)
    # Skip the current element and go to i+1
    arr2 = solveDP(i + 1)
    if sum(arr1) > sum(arr2):
        DP[i] = arr1[:]    # Copy arr1 into DP[i]
    else:
        DP[i] = arr2[:]    # Copy arr2 into DP[i]
    return DP[i]

mines = solveDP(0)
for x in mines: # This loop simply assigns the integers' ordered numbers, in order to track which were used
    if a.index(x) + 1 not in mineNum:
        mineNum.append(a.index(x) + 1)
```

Comment: What is `mines`? What does `solveDP()` have to do with your question?

Comment: solveDP() is being used to produce the array with the numbers that add to the max sum, and mines was just a variable I made in order to hold the that same array. Possibly redundant, but easier to type when needed several times

Comment: Ok, I think I can just about see what is happening with your recursive function. What is the meaning of `a.index(x) + 1` in the loop at the end; specifically why `+ 1`?

Comment: This is for theoretical use in determining paths to take, essentially. The + 1 is meant to start the "path numbers" at 1, rather than 0. If that may be causing a problem, feel free to point it out.

Comment: So, is the problem here that `a[]` could contain duplicates, but `DP[]` doesn't know which index in `a` its getting so the `a.index(x)` just picks the first?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, that's the issue. It is just picking the first index, rather than the corresponding index. For example, if the array contained [0, 1, 4, 2, 4, 0], The indices, 2 and 4 produce the max sum with no adjacent elements, but my code would simply produce 2. (Twice if not for the if statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I've got it. My solution is simply to include the index `i` along with `a[i]` when picking an element. The hack needed is in using `sum()` to recreate the value you are calculating.

```py
import random

numsLength = random.randint(1,100)
print(numsLength)
a = [random.randint(0, 400) for i in range(numsLength)]
DP = [[] for i in a]  # This will hold bestSeq from i, initially empty

def solveDP(i):
    if i >= len(a):
        return []

    # If this value is already computed return that value
    if DP[i]:
        return DP[i]

    # Include the current element and go to i+2
    arr1 = [(a[i],i)] + solveDP(i + 2)
    # Skip the current element and go to i+1
    arr2 = solveDP(i + 1)
    if sum(i for i, _ in arr1) > sum(i for i, _ in arr2):
        DP[i] = arr1[:]    # Copy arr1 into DP[i]
    else:
        DP[i] = arr2[:]    # Copy arr2 into DP[i]
    return DP[i]

mines = solveDP(0)

mineNum = []
for x,idx in mines:
    if idx+1 not in mineNum:
        mineNum.append(idx+1)
print(mineNum)
```

Update:

```py
DPS = [sum(i for i, _ in d) for d in DP]
print(DPS)
print(max(DPS))
```

However, it seems that your algorithm leaves the `max` as the first index in `DP`

Comment: Looking it over quickly to make sure it's producing the intended result. Not that I doubt you, just making sure. Will respond shortly. Thanks for the help, thus far!

Comment: Please test away. I'm not entirely sure I've got it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it seems to produce the intend indices. One thing I've just realized that I removed from my code was the max sum, as now I still need to produce the max sum.

Comment: Do you mean the max sum of all the sums in `DP[]`?

Comment: I do,  yes. I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face, but it's been a long day.

Comment: You can do that after calling `solveDP()`. I'll try to add that . . .